# Module for animation when link is clicked

Tags: ajax, javascript

If a user clicks ANY of the links on the drupal site I am setting up, I want to show animation before the transition to another node/page.

Is there a module for this? Or would jquery work/how would I insert this into drupal.

Here's a site that I created a long time ago, but in flash template:
http://jonesstuckey.com/

Click on ANY Link and you will see the animation.

I'm trying to apply all this flash/actionscript to my drupal site.Any suggestions

Comment: How do you want to "apply all this flash" to HTML? Flash can't animate anything that's outside Flash.

Comment: through javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can override the click event on your links, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694031/jquery-play-animation-beforeunload).

The code from that question is:

```
var goToURL = null;

$('a').click(function() {
   var goToURL = $(this).attr("href");
     $(el).delay(500 * i).animate({'left': '-300px'}, 1000, function() {window.location = gotoURL;});
     return false; // or e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the [JQuery Loadinganimation](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_loadinganimation) module for a similar reason:

> JQuery loadinganimation module shows a loading layer on page loading events.
>   These may be triggered by form submission, clicking a hyperlink or executing an AJAX call.
>
> Hyperlinks may be excluded from trigger by adding a ".noLoadingAnimation" class.
>   Further "javascript" and "#" hyperlinks are automatically excluded.
>   Loading and animation may be aborted by pressing "ESC".
>   Hope it helps!